# Connecting UIDatePicker to UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, uidatepicker

I have a local `html` file in my ios app that's displayed in a `UIWebView`. This HTML displays a oriental date. My question is how could I connect a `UIDatePicker` to this `UIWebview`?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="birthday">
```

No need to mix Objective-C and HTML here, it's generally not a good thing to do anyway and will cause rejection on the App Store.

Comment: Ok, I added this code and i have a input box below my date, What would I type into the box to change the date?